# Float Number Ordering - Django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I try to order by accessor a `django-tables2` table on a float value column.

## tables.py

```
class GeneTable(tables.Table):
    float_number = tables.Column()

    def render_float_number(self, value):
        print(float(value))
        return float(value)
```

## input on the table

```
100.0
99.65
100.0
81.76
97.88
96.96
97.57
69.87
97.87
```

## result after sort by clicking on accessor

```
100.0
100.0
69.87
81.76
96.96
97.57
97.87
97.88
99.65
```

How solve this sort problem ?